# Error in is.finite(x) when plotting polygons in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

After an upgrade to R 3.5.3 (under windows) and the update of all packages installed an script using ggplot is not working any more. The script bassically tries to plot a map by filling polygons based on defined levels.

```
for (i in 1:3) {

fill.var<-zona.df[i+8]    
# Mapping municipalities by level (nivel)
ggp <- ggplot(data=zona.df,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) 
ggp <- ggp + geom_polygon(aes(fill=fill.var))     # draw polygons
ggp <- ggp + geom_path(color="grey", linetype=1)  # draw boundaries
ggp <- ggp + coord_equal() + xlab(" ") + ylab(" ")
ggp <- ggp + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("green","yellow","orange","red"),na.value
= "transparent", breaks=c(0,1,2,3),labels=c("Normal","Moderado","Alto","Extremo"),
                                  limits=c(0,3)) ggp <- ggp + coord_map("lagrange")
# Overlay 28 areas 
ggp <- ggp + geom_path(data=muni.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color="grey", linetype=1)
ggp <- ggp + geom_path(data=muni_area.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color="blue", size=0.4)
# Overlay provinces 
ggp <- ggp + geom_path(data=pr.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color="black", size=1)
print(ggp)
```

Data used for filling polygons ("fill.var", 1 column x 60002 rows) comes from a dataframe named zona.df

```
> head(zona.df)
  zona       long      lat order  hole piece id group nivel1 nivel2 nivel3
1    1 -0.2777490 40.25998     1 FALSE     1  1   1.1      1      2      3
2    1 -0.2652719 40.25012     2 FALSE     1  1   1.1      1      2      3
3    1 -0.2633704 40.24859     3 FALSE     1  1   1.1      1      2      3
4    1 -0.2448370 40.23688     4 FALSE     1  1   1.1      1      2      3
5    1 -0.2418003 40.23496     5 FALSE     1  1   1.1      1      2      3
6    1 -0.2396455 40.23361     6 FALSE     1  1   1.1      1      2      3

> dput(head(zona.df,30))
structure(list(zona = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), long = c(-0.27774902, 
-0.26527193, -0.26337045, -0.24483699, -0.24180027, -0.2396455, 
-0.2348754, -0.23393393, -0.23880772, -0.24654681, -0.25187707, 
-0.26866825, -0.28338055, -0.29171539, -0.31074526, -0.31179492, 
-0.31203856, -0.31306117, -0.31369715, -0.31414035, -0.31477492, 
-0.31534867, -0.31637842, -0.31722535, -0.3175309, -0.31863818, 
-0.3202096, -0.32107671, -0.32114285, -0.33818943), lat = c(40.25998024, 
40.25011967, 40.24858841, 40.2368797, 40.23496073, 40.2336122, 
40.22491394, 40.22321599, 40.22386393, 40.21180703, 40.20347558, 
40.19665815, 40.20210305, 40.20519903, 40.20969666, 40.20959496, 
40.20967268, 40.21025494, 40.21051292, 40.21089254, 40.21118652, 
40.21123587, 40.21104359, 40.21131546, 40.21131354, 40.21094288, 
40.21012356, 40.20928791, 40.20910028, 40.22051057), order = 1:30, 
    hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
    "23"), class = "factor"), id = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "1"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1.1", "2.1", "2.2", 
    "2.3", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "4.1", "5.1", "6.1", "6.2", "6.3", 
    "6.4", "7.1", "8.1", "9.1", "10.1", "10.2", "11.1", "11.2", 
    "12.1", "12.2", "13.1", "13.2", "13.3", "13.4", "13.5", "13.6", 
    "13.7", "13.8", "14.1", "15.1", "16.1", "17.1", "17.2", "17.3", 
    "17.4", "17.5", "18.1", "18.2", "19.1", "19.2", "20.1", "20.2", 
    "20.3", "20.4", "20.5", "20.6", "20.7", "20.8", "20.9", "20.10", 
    "20.11", "20.12", "20.13", "20.14", "20.15", "20.16", "20.17", 
    "20.18", "20.19", "20.20", "20.21", "20.22", "21.1", "21.2", 
    "21.3", "21.4", "22.1", "23.1", "24.1", "24.2", "24.3", "24.4", 
    "24.5", "24.6", "24.7", "24.8", "24.9", "24.10", "24.11", 
    "24.12", "24.13", "24.14", "24.15", "24.16", "24.17", "24.18", 
    "24.19", "24.20", "24.21", "24.22", "24.23", "25.1", "26.1", 
    "27.1", "28.1"), class = "factor"), nivel1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), nivel2 = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    nivel3 = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

> class(fill.var)
[1] "data.frame"
> dput(head(fill.var,30))
structure(list(nivel1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the error message when trying to plot

```
print(ggp)
```

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type
>   data.frame. Defaulting to continuous. Error in is.finite(x) : default
>   method not implemented for type 'list'

session info:

```
> sessioninfo::session_info()
- Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
 os       Windows 7 x64 SP 1          
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        

- Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package      * version date       lib source        
 dplyr        * 0.8.0.1 2019-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 forcats      * 0.4.0   2019-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ggplot2      * 3.1.0   2018-10-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 lubridate    * 1.7.4   2018-04-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 plyr         * 1.8.4   2016-06-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 purrr        * 0.3.2   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 readr        * 1.3.1   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 rgdal        * 1.4-3   2019-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sp           * 1.3-1   2018-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 stringr      * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tibble       * 2.1.1   2019-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tidyr        * 0.8.3   2019-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tidyverse    * 1.2.1   2017-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.0)

[1] C:/Users/paco/Documents/R/win-library/3.5
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library
```

Maybe the problem comes from the point that ggplot is built under R 3.5.2? Should I downgrade ggplot2? Install dev version from github?

Thanks in advance

Comment: at first glance it seems strange that you are passing a dataframe to the `fill` parameter in `geom_polygon`. at least I have not seen this before... Have you tried `geom_polygon(data = fill.var,aes(fill = nivel1))` instead?

Comment: this may be related: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3060, it's talking about misspecified aesthetics which kind of supports my hunch that something is off with the `fill` parameter

Comment: @jludewig fill.var is built in a for loop as `fill.var<-zona.df[k]` I have also tried to use `geom_polygon(aes(fill=zona.df[k]))`. Your suggestion yields another error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'long' not found`

Comment: my guess is there is now something wrong with the "long" variable in your `zona.df` dataframe but it's hard to debug in this fashion. Can you paste a minimal example of your data that breaks in your environment?

Comment: This code is running on an "older" R installation in another linux server and was working under Windows before the R and ggplot update, not sure the problem comes from a variable in zona.df

Comment: I think you need to change call to `geom_polygon` to `geom_polygon(aes(fill=fill.var[1]))`. This worked for me. The previous suggestion I made (`geom_polygon(data = fill.var,aes(fill = nivel1))`) resulted in a situation where ggplot was looking for the `long` variable in the `fill.var` dataframe which it obviously could not find. let me know if this helped.

Comment: I think in general it would be preferable to construct a dataframe in your loop which contains all the data needed to create the plot instead of getting data from two or more different dataframes.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion `geom_polygon(aes(fill=fill.var[1]))` but the error still persists. Which version of ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: Script works if I change to `geom_polygon(aes(fill=zona.df$nivel1))` but as in the plot I want to use _zona.df_ columns _nivel1, nivel2_ and _nivel3_ I created _fill.var_

Comment: It runs for me using ggplot2 version 3.0.0 and R 3.5.1 (cannot post my full session_info as a comment...). Not sure if that helps you. To me this looks like an issue as to how ggplot evaluates the variable names. I'm out of my depth here sorry

Comment: One thing you may want to look into: Since you are only looping over the different nivel columns, maybe you can change your loop to iterate over the column names and plug in the values into the aesthethics. There is a version that allows for programmatic definition of the aesthetics: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html